# How is an ARM Cortex CPU Over/Underclocked at the software level?

Tags: arm

Where is the register located? Also, what are the different locations of registers that can be used for configuration of an ARM CPU and how does the CPU access them?

Comment: Overclocking works the same way as pretty much any other CPU - by some other part of the system exposing programmable control of the clock generator, if at all - unless you specify a specific board/chip there's no right answer. For system registers, there are dozens, documented by hundreds of pages in the architecture manual and specific processor manuals - that's way to broad for here.

Comment: You could utilize `cpufreq` if it was Linux...

Comment: oops, I meant different locations that store a group of registers (e.g. C15). I didn't mean list all the registers lol, my bad.